# How do I preserve whitespace between floated elements?

Tags: css

I have a container with some spans which have the CSS property `float:left`, the items have some space between them, my problem is that the whitespace collapses when the container is too small to show it, as demonstrated in the example below

```css
.root {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:lightgray;
  width:200px;
  margin:50px;
}

body>div:nth-of-type(2){
  width:180px;
}

.item {
  float:left;
  border:1px solid gray;
  padding:2px 5px;
  background-color:white;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.spc {
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  width:20px;
  height:1px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class=root>
    <span class=item>item a1</span>
    <span class=item>item a2</span>
    <span class=spc></span>
    <span class=item>item b1</span>
</div>  

<div class=root>
    <span class=item>item a1</span>
    <span class=item>item a2</span>
    <span class=spc></span>
    <span class=item>item b1</span>
</div>
```

Also, what's with the weird alignment of the third item?

---

I have slightly elaborated my example:

```js
var rainbow=['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','indigo','violet'];
var $=v=>document.querySelector(v);
var root=$('#root');
var item=$('.item');
item.remove();
var spc=$('.spc');
spc.remove();

var data ={
  a:2,b:1,c:1
};
update();

function update(){  
  Object.keys(data).forEach((key,i)=>{
    for(var j=0;j<data[key];j++){
      var nitem=item.cloneNode();
      nitem.textContent='item '+key+j;
      root.append(nitem);
    }      
    var nspc=spc.cloneNode(true);
    let col=rainbow[i];
    nspc.style.backgroundColor=col;
    nspc.onclick=e=>alert(`i hope you have a ${col} day`);
    root.append(nspc);
  });
}
```

```css
#root {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:lightgray;
  width:250px;
  margin:50px;
  vertical-align:top;
  padding:5px;
}

.item {
  float:left;
  border:1px solid gray;
  padding:2px 5px;
  background-color:white;
  white-space:nowrap;
  margin:2px;
}

.spc {
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  width:20px;
  background-color:lightblue;
  border:1px solid transparent;
  padding:2px 5px;  
  margin:2px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id=root>
    <span class=item>item a1</span>
    <span class=spc>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

I work primarily on single page applications where the ui requirements often push the boundaries of standard layout guides.
I provide a link to a [codepen - empty elements](https://codepen.io/matt-2016/pen/yLqPpGo) which extends the above idea further by allowing the root container to be resized, this shows that there is room for improvement in this model.

This all leads to potentially new features of css, one namely a margin that should always appear between two elements, either horizontally or vertically.

In my current working example i dont as yet have need to style or add events to the 'spaces', but undoubtedly version 99 in 2050 will do, for instance to select some sub group of items

Going down the margin route, I could if it existed, have used some sort of css selector

```
.itemX:last-of-type {
    margin-right:20px;
}
```

The trouble with this approach is that I am forced to create different classes for every type of item.

Comment: don't use an element to create space. Use margin, gap, etc

Comment: yeah i was going to clarify this, sometimes the space is present and sometimes not, thankyou for the comment, could you possibly provide some references for not using an element to create a space where its needed or is just your preference

Comment: it's not a preference and it doesn't need a reference. margin exists since decades (like padding, border, etc) and you can control if they are applied or not, the same way you control the presence of your element

Comment: the space is not a margin, padding etc, its more like an empty element, for instance if item a2 were removed i would have to transfer the margin etc onto another element, i know it sounds funky to say dont use an element to create space use margin,padding etc, but i feel this is a short sighted statement

Comment: well, your example is a clear indication that using an element as a "space" is not a good choice. If you describe what you want to achieve including all the requirements (even the fact that some element may disappear) you will get answers that don't use elements as space

Comment: The element is still there but because you've given it a height of 1px the float:left of the next div is positioning it below that element. If you put a background colour on the spc class you'll see it's still there and has a width of 20px. It's not collapsing at all.

Comment: @TemaniAfif and the independent comment directly after yours, "style it lightblue" sugguests that it is

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `diplay: flex` and create space with `CSS`, not with `HTML` element, This is my example:

```css
.root {
  display:flex;
  background-color:lightgray;
  width:200px;
  margin:50px;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 5%;
}

body>div:nth-of-type(2){
  width:120px;
}

.item {
  border:1px solid gray;
  padding:2px 5px;
  background-color:white;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class=root>
    <span class=item>item 1</span>
    <span class=item>item 2</span>
</div>  

<div class=root>
    <span class=item>item 1</span>
    <span class=item>item 2</span>
</div>
```